# vscode Regular expression search?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

windows7+vscode Version: 1.27.1

With vscode, I tried this

```
input----------------------------------------------
<aaa>001</aaa>
<bbb>002</bbb>
<ccc>003</ccc>

operation------------------------------------------
Ctrl+Shift+F
SEARCH
^(<aaa>)(.*)(</aaa>)(.*)$|^(<bbb>)(.*)(</bbb>)(.*)$

output---------------------------------------------
1,1: <aaa>001</aaa>
2,1: <bbb>002</bbb>
```

please tell me

I wnat operation one liner

I want output ---> 0001,002

SEARCH?
from aaa to b

ーーーーーー
2018ー9ー17

Find: ^(?!.(aaa|bbb)).$

Replace: leave empty

Find:.(.)\n.(.)\n

Replace: $1,$2

I can not one liner

asterrlsk disappeared

Comment: `(?<=<aaa>).*(?=</aaa>)|(?<=<bbb>).*(?=</bbb>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, it is two separate find & replace actions, both use the regular expression option.

Find: `<.*?>|</.*?>`

Replace: *leave empty*

---

Find: `$\n`

Replace: `,`